# Этимология слова "ручка"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие корни у слов "ручка" и "рука"?

Comment: Это ответ на ваш вопрос или же сам вопрос? Если вопрос, то что вас интересует: корни этих слов или же  сама этимология? 

Answer (score 1):

Вы о канцелярской ручке?

"ручка"-корень руч= суфф.-к-(к//ч) и "рука"-корень рук.
Ручка - от рука.

Сначала были гусиные перья, потом их заменили металлическими и посадили на рукоять-деталь, за которую мы держимся рукой при письме - ручка с пером, а потом уже появились чернильные,шариковые ручки, роллеры, а название осталось то же, привычное, а вот в Болгарии - писалка, химикалка и т.д.